# Polymer Paper datatable - run function if value is changed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

David Mulder has this cool paper element - paper datatable.

I can't figure out how to run a function when the table was edited.

Isn't the code supposed to be something like this:

```
<paper-datatable-column
                                                                header="Name"
                                                                property="name"
                                                                type="String"
                                                                on-change="{{testFunction}}"
                                                                style="max-width: 50px"
                                                                editable dialog
                                                                sortable>
</paper-datatable-column>
```

Thanks for your help!
Zvi Karp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#change-callbacks) on the data bind to paper-datatable data property.

Here is one example, [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/k4B2H0whGXROcvXnbx9y?p=preview)

```
observers: [
   'data_changed(data.*)'
],
data_changed: function() {
   console.log('data_changed');
},
```

Comment: works excellent! (I didn't know you can do that)! but I don't really need it. I'm uploading the changed data to a database so I need to run a function when the user is finished editing the filed. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: You mean something as Save button?

Comment: yes. but I have lots of data in the table and I don't want to re-save all of it if one word was changed.

Comment: Thats exactly what observers are doing - giving you just changed field path and new value. 
I have updated the plunk, check in data_changed() func.

Comment: I only want to get the data then the user presses enter or clicks off the paper input. if I well use data_changed() it well save the data every time the user adds a letter, not when he finishes. It's possible to use your function with a save button, but I prefer not to have one.

Comment: The answer you gave me is a work-around. not using paper-datatable 'get-changed' but using polymer's observers. but thanks!